# swift 3 add row to TableViewController using textField from ViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a todolist app in swift. Here is what it looks like :

[image]

So far to create a todo I used an alertController but I changed it and now using a new viewcontroller opening when click on the "+" to add. When the ViewController opens itself, I fill the title and then click a button. On the click button I'd like it to add a new row in the tableViewController with the title I put in the textField of the viewController.
I'm having trouble to pass the value of the textField in the new row created in the tableViewController.
Anyone can give some help ?

[EDIT] 
Here is my addTodoController :

```
var updateTableViewClosure: ((String) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func AddButton(_ sender: Any) {
        var todoValue = titleField.text
        updateTableViewClosure?(todoValue!)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!
```

Here is my tableviewcontroller :

```
if segue.identifier == "CreateAdd" {

    let addItemViewController = segue.destination as! CreateAdd
    addItemViewController.updateTableViewClosure = {
        newItem in myItems(title: todoValue, content:"hello", ontent: "Ceci est le contenu" , startDate: "16/08/1997", author: "Clem")
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> " Use of unresolved "todoValue"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to pass data back to the view controller containing the table view. This can be achieved in many ways, for example using the delegate pattern.

One simpler way to achieve that is using closures, like this:

In the view controller containing the table view:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "identifier" {

        let addItemViewController = segue.destination as! AddItemViewController
        addItemViewController.updateTableViewClosure = {
            newItem in

            // Add the new item to your data source and reload your table view.
        }
    }
}
```

In `AddItemViewController` add a new variable called `updateTableViewClosure` which will be your closure:

```
var updateTableViewClosure: (String -> Void)?
```

and call it wherever you want like this:

```
updateTableViewClosure?("The new item")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! But I don't understand how the textField Value is going to be get and add in the TableViewController new row ?

Comment: You could do that by adding a button for example, and in the `IBAction` of that button, get the text from the textfeild and call `updateTableViewClosure`.
You could also do it by setting the view controller as the textfield's delegate, and implementing `textFieldShouldReturn` delegate method.

Comment: This is actually what I'm having trouble with, how to access the text of my textField's viewController in the tableViewController ?

Comment: You need to think about it in the opposite direction, how to update the table view based on the text entered in the text field? And this is what I explained in my answer.

Comment: updateTableViewClosure?("the New Item") -> the new Item here should be the text from textfield ?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass the text from the text field here.

Comment: One last thing, I don't understand how's all of this is being called by the button "add" in tableviewcontroller ?

Comment: Add button only shows the other view controller (the view controller containing the text field). Add a button next to the text field name it save for example, and get the text of the text field and pass it to the `updateTableViewClosure`.

Comment: I updated my post so you can see what i've done, i'm obviouslsy missing something

Comment: Great, you're done. You only need to replace `newItem` with `todoValue`. You need to read more about closures in Swift to understand how it works. Good luck!